# How to remove the data from a string from particular character to particular character?

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring

How to remove the data from a string from particular character to particular character?

I have a

```
string data = "OK;;183.82.185.36;IN;India;Telangana;Hyderabad;500018;17.3753;78.4744;+05:30"
```

I need India, Telangana and hyderabad in different string variables to store the IP address location

```
string ipLocationurl = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=0fb2d511503c450d077144d9a62194a12521db296995266977c6d4e&ip=183.82.185.36";
StreamReader stream = URLServerRequest(ipLocationurl);
string response = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: is this about removing or extracting?

Comment: we have to extract disered address if ip . rest of that we can remove.or leave it @fubo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the data string on each ";" and then assign to different variables the elements you need from the resulting array

```
var splitResult=data.Split(';');
var first=splitResult[4];
var second=splitResult[5];
var third=splitResult[6];
```

Comment: What if the order changes or there are fewer elements than expected?

Comment: order will not changes in api results, as i think im not sure @dtsg

Comment: I suppose that is a standard response from a webservice, and as you can see from the empty second (1-index) element, it will always have the same number of elements, because if some is missing there will still be the ";" for that element.

Comment: it's the string you provided in your question

Comment: but im getting error . saying some invalid arguments 

  var splitResult = response.Split(";");@SaverioTerracciano

Comment: @fubo sorry, fixed that with a char

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78897/discussion-between-coder-and-saverio-terracciano).